# Adding a drop down inside bootstrap buttons row with ruby code output

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

On my Rails app I have a *row* of buttons, I want to make one of them into a drop down menu that will present items extracted from a db table, the ruby code works but I can't get it to appear as a drop down.

Here is the ruby code:

```
<% @all_makes.each do |allMakesDisplay| %>
  <a id="allMakesDisplay"><%= link_to allMakesDisplay.name, make_index_path(make_name: allMakesDisplay.name) %></a>
<% end %>
```

And this is the row with the drop down:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse top-bar" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <a href="/dealership/category/make">Makes</a>
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <% @all_makes.each do |allMakesDisplay| %>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="<%= link_to allMakesDisplay.name, dealership_category_make_path(allMakesDisplay) %>"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block">
        <a href="blog.html">Models</a>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block">
        <a href="contact.html">My Portfolio</a>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `MAKES` should be the drop down, the are 12 items that should be returned.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on:

- The `#each` loop should be inside `<ul>`.
- `link_to` will create an anchor tag `<a>`, so it should not be used as a `href` attribute. [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse top-bar" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <a href="/dealership/category/make">Makes</a>
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <!--for each element, create a <li> (not <ul>)-->
            <% @all_makes.each do |allMakesDisplay| %>
            <li>
              <%= link_to allMakesDisplay.name, 
                          dealership_category_make_path(allMakesDisplay) %>
            </li>
           <% end %> <!-- end #each loop-->
          </ul>
          
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block">
        <a href="blog.html">Models</a>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block">
        <a href="contact.html">My Portfolio</a>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I corrected it. now it shows the list of links under the button all the time. they do work but the drop down doesn't:
   ```<div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block">Makes
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul id="makers-button-makers-list">
          <% @all_makes.each do |allMakesDisplay| %>
          <li><%= link_to allMakesDisplay.name, make_index_path(make_name: allMakesDisplay.name) %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So, the dropdown is OK, but it does not expand when you click on it? If so, did you add JQuery and Bootstrap JavaScript to the assets? And `button` must have the class `dropdown-toggle`

Comment: No, the drop down does not function. all of the data that supposed to 'drop down' just sits as a <ul> under it. all the time, the button does have the class. I did not require the JQuery, Bootstrap and JavaScript.
Sorry about the messy comments. it accept only mini markdown, not too friendly

Comment: No problem :) But you need to add JQuery and Booststrap JavaScript for it to work. The `dropdown` is a JS plugin.

Comment: I required all of the above. still doesn't work. I don't know if it matters but the whole thing is in a `partial`.  These are the lines:
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: If you are using `bootstrap-sass` gem, just follow the instructions of how to require the JS files on `application.js`. JQuery is shipped with Rails. Adding assets like you are doing will cause you problem, but this should be in another question